# Does std::steady_clock make overhead in comparison to std::system_clock?

Tags: c++, clock

I'm using C++ chrono functions to query current time many times per second in a game main loop.

Disregarding correctness of using `std::system_clock` vs `std::steady_clock` for this purpose, does `steady_clock` make more overhead then `system_clock`.

Help on any platforms and library implementations would be appreciated.

Comment: Benchmark them on your platform. Look up `rdtsc`.

Comment: _"Disregarding correctness"_ but why????????

Comment: Check your platforms documentation. It's allowable for them to be aliases for the same thing